# laravel - foreach repeat many times

Tags: laravel, for-loop, foreach

I have two model : `User` & `Book`. I want create a book for each user with a specific QR code

```
$users = User::get();
$date = ... ;
$finalCount = 0;
$code = 150;
$userCount = count($users);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $book = new Book();
    $book->unique_id = uniqid('', true);
    $book->user_id = $user->unique_id;
    $book->code = "PP-" . strval(mt_rand(100, 999)) . strval($code);
    $book->create_date = $date;
    $book->status = 'active';
    $book->save();

    $QRCode = new BaconQrCodeGenerator;
    $file = public_path('/images/book/' . $book->code . '.png');
    $QRCode->encoding('UTF-8')
        ->format('png')
        ->merge('/public/image/logo.png', .15)
        ->size(1000)
        ->generate($book->unique_id, $file);
    if (File::exists($file))
        $finalCount++;
    $code++;
    if ($finalCount == $userCount)
        break;
}
```

After this function called, i have 20 book for each user. I used an `if` statement for break the loop ( `if ($finalCount == $userCount)` ) but it doesn't work.
I can't understand whats going on here and also i have not any error log

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$file = public_path('/images/book/' . $book->code . '.png');
```

try

```
$file = public_path().'/images/book/' . $book->code . '.png';
```

Comment: Is it important ? I don't think your way solve this problem

Comment: Wait, so according to your logic, it will only break if the $finalCount is equal to total number of users. For that to be true, File should exist each time it goes through the loop. So it will only do a break once, at the end of the loop. Which is unnecessary.

Comment: It's not my question. But they are same in action

Comment: I have my files and everything's fine @AmitozDeol ... The only problem is repeating event

Comment: Yes they are same @ArashHatami ... I test my code using two way for getting path